# Can we set multiple values to modle in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to **backbone** and **nodejs**, I have made a demo which used backbone and nodejs for updating and inserting data. I'm able to send put request with single data at a time.

```
this.model.set({    
    user_id:Session.get('userid'),
    seat_id:seatId
});
this.model.save({
     success: function() {
        // do some stuff here
        alert("a")
     },
     error: function() {
        // do other stuff here
        alert("b")
     }
    })
```

The above code post single row info to server. I want to send multiple info to server at a time. Can we set model something like below

```
this.model.set([{
   user_id:Session.get('userid'),
   seat_id:2
},{
   user_id:Session.get('userid'),
   seat_id:3
}]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```
arr = [{
   user_id:Session.get('userid'),
   seat_id:2
},{
   user_id:Session.get('userid'),
   seat_id:3
}];
this.model.set(sessions, arr);
```